# Calculating the square of BigInteger

Tags: c#, math, .net-4.0, complexity-theory, biginteger

I'm using .NET 4's [System.Numerics.BigInteger structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268287.aspx).

I need to calculate the square (x<sup>2</sup>) of very large numbers - **millions of decimal digits**.

If `x` is a `BigInteger`, What is the time complexity of:

```
x*x;
```

or

```
BigInteger.Pow(x,2);
```

?

How can multiply such big numbers in the fastest way using .NET 4 BigInteger? Is there an implementation for [Schönhage–Strassen algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm)?

Comment: Holy bajeebers, what are you going to do with a number millions of decimal digits large?  The number of particles in the universe is estimated to be representable with less than 90 decimal digits.

Comment: True, but not every integer is used for counting physical properties.  As but one trivial example, the largest known primes are far bigger than 90 digits already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends on how large your numbers are. As the Wikipedia page tells you:

> In practice the Schönhage–Strassen algorithm starts to outperform older methods such as Karatsuba and Toom–Cook multiplication for numbers beyond 2<sup>2<sup>15</sup></sup> to 2<sup>2<sup>17</sup></sup> (10,000 to 40,000 decimal digits).

`System.Numerics.BigInteger` uses the [Karatsuba algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) or standard schoolbook multiplication, depending on the size of the numbers. Karatsuba has a time complexity of O(*n* <sup>log<sub>2</sub> 3</sup>). But if your numbers are smaller than above quoted figures, then you likely won't see much speedup from implementing Schönhage–Strassen.

As for `Pow()` this itself squares the number at least once during its calculations (and it does that by simply doing `num * num` – so I think this won't be more efficient, either.

Comment: I've updated my question, I'm talking about millions of decimal digits.

Answer (score 2):

A quite simple method to implement is based on FFT. Since multiplying two numbers amounts to perform a convolution of their coefficients followed by a pass to eliminate carries, you should be able to do the convolution in O(n log n) operations via FFT methods (n = number of digits).

Numerical recipes has a chapter on this. This is definitely faster than divide and conquer methods, like Karatsuba, for such big numbers.

Comment: This is how GIMPS squares numbers and is definitely the fastest solution for the OP's situation. One point of contention is that an FFT is a divide and conquer method. This is because the number being squared is converted to a coefficient vector.

Answer (score 2):

- First of All,`System.Numerics.BigInteger` does NOT use the [Karatsuba
  algorithm] with O(n <sup>0.5</sup> ) and it uses standard schoolbook multiplication O(n <sup>2</sup> ).
- By this code you can Multiple two 30,000 bit (approximately 9000 decimal digit) in Just 1.4 millisecond.

  ```
       public  void benchMark()
       {
           Xint U, V,Temp;
           int n = 30000;
           while (n > 29000)
           {
               U = RND(n << 1);
               //_______________________
               sw.Restart();
               Temp = U * U;
               sw.Stop();
               label7.Text = Convert.ToString("Micro " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " ms");
               //_______________________

           }
        n>>=1;
       }

       public static Xint MTP(Xint U, Xint V)
       {
           return MTP(U, V, Xint.Max(U.Sign * U, V.Sign * V).ToByteArray().Length << 3);
       }
       public static Xint MTP(Xint U, Xint V, int n)
       {
           if (n <= 3000) return U * V;
           if (n <= 6000) return TC2(U, V, n);
           if (n <= 10000) return TC3(U, V, n);
           if (n <= 40000) return TC4(U, V, n);
           return TC2P(U, V, n);
       }
       private static Xint MTPr(Xint U, Xint V, int n)
       {
           if (n <= 3000) return U * V;
           if (n <= 6000) return TC2(U, V, n);
           if (n <= 10000) return TC3(U, V, n);
           return TC4(U, V, n);
       }
       private static Xint TC2(Xint U1, Xint V1, int n)
       {
           n >>= 1;
           Xint Mask = (Xint.One << n) - 1;
           Xint U0 = U1 & Mask; U1 >>= n;
           Xint V0 = V1 & Mask; V1 >>= n;
           Xint P0 = MTPr(U0, V0, n);
           Xint P2 = MTPr(U1, V1, n);
           return ((P2 << n) + (MTPr(U0 + U1, V0 + V1, n) - (P0 + P2)) << n) + P0;
       }
       private static Xint TC3(Xint U2, Xint V2, int n)
       {
           n = (int)((long)(n) * 0x55555556 >> 32); // n /= 3;
           Xint Mask = (Xint.One << n) - 1;
           Xint U0 = U2 & Mask; U2 >>= n;
           Xint U1 = U2 & Mask; U2 >>= n;
           Xint V0 = V2 & Mask; V2 >>= n;
           Xint V1 = V2 & Mask; V2 >>= n;
           Xint W0 = MTPr(U0, V0, n);
           Xint W4 = MTPr(U2, V2, n);
           Xint P3 = MTPr((((U2 << 1) + U1) << 1) + U0, (((V2 << 1) + V1 << 1)) + V0, n);
           U2 += U0;
           V2 += V0;
           Xint P2 = MTPr(U2 - U1, V2 - V1, n);
           Xint P1 = MTPr(U2 + U1, V2 + V1, n);
           Xint W2 = (P1 + P2 >> 1) - (W0 + W4);
           Xint W3 = W0 - P1;
           W3 = ((W3 + P3 - P2 >> 1) + W3) / 3 - (W4 << 1);
           Xint W1 = P1 - (W4 + W3 + W2 + W0);
           return ((((W4 << n) + W3 << n) + W2 << n) + W1 << n) + W0;
       }
       private static Xint TC4(Xint U3, Xint V3, int n)
       {
           n >>= 2;
           Xint Mask = (Xint.One << n) - 1;
           Xint U0 = U3 & Mask; U3 >>= n;
           Xint U1 = U3 & Mask; U3 >>= n;
           Xint U2 = U3 & Mask; U3 >>= n;
           Xint V0 = V3 & Mask; V3 >>= n;
           Xint V1 = V3 & Mask; V3 >>= n;
           Xint V2 = V3 & Mask; V3 >>= n;

           Xint W0 = MTPr(U0, V0, n);                               //  0
           U0 += U2; U1 += U3;
           V0 += V2; V1 += V3;
           Xint P1 = MTPr(U0 + U1, V0 + V1, n);                     //  1
           Xint P2 = MTPr(U0 - U1, V0 - V1, n);                     // -1
           U0 += 3 * U2; U1 += 3 * U3;
           V0 += 3 * V2; V1 += 3 * V3;
           Xint P3 = MTPr(U0 + (U1 << 1), V0 + (V1 << 1), n);       //  2
           Xint P4 = MTPr(U0 - (U1 << 1), V0 - (V1 << 1), n);       // -2
           Xint P5 = MTPr(U0 + 12 * U2 + ((U1 + 12 * U3) << 2),
                          V0 + 12 * V2 + ((V1 + 12 * V3) << 2), n); //  4
           Xint W6 = MTPr(U3, V3, n);                               //  inf

           Xint W1 = P1 + P2;
           Xint W4 = (((((P3 + P4) >> 1) - (W1 << 1)) / 3 + W0) >> 2) - 5 * W6;
           Xint W2 = (W1 >> 1) - (W6 + W4 + W0);
           P1 = P1 - P2;
           P4 = P4 - P3;
           Xint W5 = ((P1 >> 1) + (5 * P4 + P5 - W0 >> 4) - ((((W6 << 4) + W4) << 4) + W2)) / 45;
           W1 = ((P4 >> 2) + (P1 << 1)) / 3 + (W5 << 2);
           Xint W3 = (P1 >> 1) - (W1 + W5);
           return ((((((W6 << n) + W5 << n) + W4 << n) + W3 << n) + W2 << n) + W1 << n) + W0;
       }
       private static Xint TC2P(Xint A, Xint B, int n)
       {
           n >>= 1;
           Xint Mask = (Xint.One << n) - 1;
           Xint[] U = new Xint[3];
           U[0] = A & Mask; A >>= n; U[2] = A; U[1] = U[0] + A;
           Xint[] V = new Xint[3];
           V[0] = B & Mask; B >>= n; V[2] = B; V[1] = V[0] + B;
           Xint[] P = new Xint[3];
           Parallel.For(0, 3, (int i) => P[i] = MTPr(U[i], V[i], n));
           return ((P[2] << n) + P[1] - (P[0] + P[2]) << n) + P[0];
       }

       private static long current_n;
      private static Xint Product(int n)
       {
           if (n > 2) return MTP(Product(n - (n >>= 1)), Product(n));
           if (n > 1) return (current_n += 2) * (current_n += 2);
           return current_n += 2;
       }

       public static Xint[] DQR(Xint A, Xint B)
       {
           int n = bL(B);
           int m = bL(A) - n;
           if (m <= 6000) return SmallDivRem(A, B);
           int signA = A.Sign; A *= signA;
           int signB = B.Sign; B *= signB;
           Xint[] QR = new Xint[2];
           if (m <= n) QR = D21(A, B, n);
           else
           {
               Xint Mask = (Xint.One << n) - 1;
               m /= n;
               Xint[] U = new Xint[m];
               int i = 0;
               for (; i < m; i++)
               {
                   U[i] = A & Mask;
                   A >>= n;
               }
               QR = D21(A, B, n);
               A = QR[0];
               for (i--; i >= 0; i--)
               {
                   QR = D21(QR[1] << n | U[i], B, n);
                   A = A << n | QR[0];
               }
               QR[0] = A;
           }
           QR[0] *= signA * signB;
           QR[1] *= signA;
           return QR;
       }
       private static Xint[] SmallDivRem(Xint A, Xint B)
       {
           Xint[] QR = new Xint[2];
           QR[0] = Xint.DivRem(A, B, out QR[1]);
           return QR;
       }
       private static Xint[] D21(Xint A, Xint B, int n)
       {
           if (n <= 6000) return SmallDivRem(A, B);
           int s = n & 1;
           A <<= s;
           B <<= s;
           n++;
           n >>= 1;
           Xint Mask = (Xint.One << n) - 1;
           Xint B1 = B >> n;
           Xint B2 = B & Mask;
           Xint[] QR1 = D32(A >> (n << 1), A >> n & Mask, B, B1, B2, n);
           Xint[] QR2 = D32(QR1[1], A & Mask, B, B1, B2, n);
           QR2[0] |= QR1[0] << n;
           QR2[1] >>= s;
           return QR2;
       }
       private static Xint[] D32(Xint A12, Xint A3, Xint B, Xint B1, Xint B2, int n)
       {
           Xint[] QR = new Xint[2];
           if ((A12 >> n) != B1) QR = D21(A12, B1, n);
           else
           {
               QR[0] = (Xint.One << n) - 1;
               QR[1] = A12 + B1 - (B1 << n);
           }
           QR[1] = (QR[1] << n | A3) - MTP(QR[0], B2, n);
           while (QR[1] < 0)
           {
               QR[0] -= 1;
               QR[1] += B;
           }
           return QR;
       }

       public static Xint SQ(Xint U)
       {
           return SQ(U, U.Sign * U.ToByteArray().Length << 3);
       }
       public static Xint SQ(Xint U, int n)
       {
           if (n <= 700) return U * U;
           if (n <= 3000) return Xint.Pow(U, 2);
           if (n <= 6000) return SQ2(U, n);
           if (n <= 10000) return SQ3(U, n);
           if (n <= 40000) return SQ4(U, n);
           return SQ2P(U, n);
       }
       private static Xint SQr(Xint U, int n)
       {
           if (n <= 3000) return Xint.Pow(U, 2);
           if (n <= 6000) return SQ2(U, n);
           if (n <= 10000) return SQ3(U, n);
           return SQ4(U, n);
       }
       private static Xint SQ2(Xint U1, int n)
       {
           n >>= 1;
           Xint U0 = U1 & ((Xint.One << n) - 1); U1 >>= n;
           Xint P0 = SQr(U0, n);
           Xint P2 = SQr(U1, n);
           return ((P2 << n) + (SQr(U0 + U1, n) - (P0 + P2)) << n) + P0;
       }
       private static Xint SQ3(Xint U2, int n)
       {
           n = (int)((long)(n) * 0x55555556 >> 32);
           Xint Mask = (Xint.One << n) - 1;
           Xint U0 = U2 & Mask; U2 >>= n;
           Xint U1 = U2 & Mask; U2 >>= n;
           Xint W0 = SQr(U0, n);
           Xint W4 = SQr(U2, n);
           Xint P3 = SQr((((U2 << 1) + U1) << 1) + U0, n);
           U2 += U0;
           Xint P2 = SQr(U2 - U1, n);
           Xint P1 = SQr(U2 + U1, n);
           Xint W2 = (P1 + P2 >> 1) - (W0 + W4);
           Xint W3 = W0 - P1;
           W3 = ((W3 + P3 - P2 >> 1) + W3) / 3 - (W4 << 1);
           Xint W1 = P1 - (W4 + W3 + W2 + W0);
           return ((((W4 << n) + W3 << n) + W2 << n) + W1 << n) + W0;
       }
       private static Xint SQ4(Xint U3, int n)
       {
           n >>= 2;
           Xint Mask = (Xint.One << n) - 1;
           Xint U0 = U3 & Mask; U3 >>= n;
           Xint U1 = U3 & Mask; U3 >>= n;
           Xint U2 = U3 & Mask; U3 >>= n;
           Xint W0 = SQr(U0, n);                                   //  0
           U0 += U2;
           U1 += U3;
           Xint P1 = SQr(U0 + U1, n);                              //  1
           Xint P2 = SQr(U0 - U1, n);                              // -1
           U0 += 3 * U2;
           U1 += 3 * U3;
           Xint P3 = SQr(U0 + (U1 << 1), n);                       //  2
           Xint P4 = SQr(U0 - (U1 << 1), n);                       // -2
           Xint P5 = SQr(U0 + 12 * U2 + ((U1 + 12 * U3) << 2), n); //  4
           Xint W6 = SQr(U3, n);                                   //  inf
           Xint W1 = P1 + P2;
           Xint W4 = (((((P3 + P4) >> 1) - (W1 << 1)) / 3 + W0) >> 2) - 5 * W6;
           Xint W2 = (W1 >> 1) - (W6 + W4 + W0);
           P1 = P1 - P2;
           P4 = P4 - P3;
           Xint W5 = ((P1 >> 1) + (5 * P4 + P5 - W0 >> 4) - ((((W6 << 4) + W4) << 4) + W2)) / 45;
           W1 = ((P4 >> 2) + (P1 << 1)) / 3 + (W5 << 2);
           Xint W3 = (P1 >> 1) - (W1 + W5);
           return ((((((W6 << n) + W5 << n) + W4 << n) + W3 << n) + W2 << n) + W1 << n) + W0;
       }
       private static Xint SQ2P(Xint A, int n)
       {
           n >>= 1;
           Xint[] U = new Xint[3];
           U[0] = A & ((Xint.One << n) - 1); A >>= n; U[2] = A; U[1] = U[0] + A;
           Xint[] P = new Xint[3];
           Parallel.For(0, 3, (int i) => P[i] = SQr(U[i], n));
           return ((P[2] << n) + P[1] - (P[0] + P[2]) << n) + P[0];
       }

       public static Xint POW(Xint X, int y)
       {
           if (y > 1) return ((y & 1) == 1) ? SQ(POW(X, y >> 1)) * X : SQ(POW(X, y >> 1));
           if (y == 1) return X;
           return 1;
       }

       public static Xint[] SR(Xint A)
       {
           return SR(A, bL(A));
       }
       public static Xint[] SR(Xint A, int n)
       {
           if (n < 53) return SR52(A);
           int m = n >> 2;
           Xint Mask = (Xint.One << m) - 1;
           Xint A0 = A & Mask; A >>= m;
           Xint A1 = A & Mask; A >>= m;
           Xint[] R = SR(A, n - (m << 1));
           Xint[] D = DQR(R[1] << m | A1, R[0] << 1);
           R[0] = (R[0] << m) + D[0];
           R[1] = (D[1] << m | A0) - SQ(D[0], m);
           if (R[1] < 0)
           {
               R[0] -= 1;
               R[1] += (R[0] << 1) | 1;
           }
           return R;
       }
       private static Xint[] SR52(Xint A)
       {
           double a = (double)A;
           long q = (long)Math.Sqrt(a);
           long r = (long)(a) - q * q;
           Xint[] QR = { q, r };
           return QR;
       }

       public static Xint SRO(Xint A)
       {
           return SRO(A, bL(A));
       }
       public static Xint SRO(Xint A, int n)
       {
           if (n < 53) return (int)Math.Sqrt((double)A);
           Xint[] R = SROr(A, n, 1);
           return R[0];
       }
       private static Xint[] SROr(Xint A, int n, int rc) // rc=recursion counter
       {
           if (n < 53) return SR52(A);
           int m = n >> 2;
           Xint Mask = (Xint.One << m) - 1;
           Xint A0 = A & Mask; A >>= m;
           Xint A1 = A & Mask; A >>= m;
           Xint[] R = SROr(A, n - (m << 1), rc + 1);
           Xint[] D = DQR((R[1] << m) | A1, R[0] << 1);
           R[0] = (R[0] << m) + D[0];
           rc--;
           if (rc != 0)
           {
               R[1] = (D[1] << m | A0) - SQ(D[0], m);
               if (R[1] < 0)
               {
                   R[0] -= 1;
                   R[1] += (R[0] << 1) | 1;
               }
               return R;
           }
           n = (bL(D[0]) << 1) - bL(D[1] << m | A0);
           if (n < 0) return R;
           if (n > 1)
           {
               R[0] -= 1;
               return R;
           }
           int shift = (bL(D[0]) - 31) << 1;
           long d0 = (int)(D[0] >> (shift >> 1));
           long d = (long)((D[1] >> (shift - m)) | (A0 >> shift)) - d0 * d0;
           if (d < 0)
           {
               R[0] -= 1;
               return R;
           }
           if (d > d0 << 1) return R;
           R[0] -= (1 - (((D[1] << m) | A0) - SQ(D[0], m)).Sign) >> 1;
           return R;
       }

       public static int bL(Xint U)
       {
           byte[] bytes = (U.Sign * U).ToByteArray();
           int i = bytes.Length - 1;
           return (i << 3) + bitLengthMostSignificantByte(bytes[i]);
       }
       private static int bitLengthMostSignificantByte(byte b)
       {
           return b < 08 ? b < 02 ? b < 01 ? 0 : 1 :
                                    b < 04 ? 2 : 3 :
                           b < 32 ? b < 16 ? 4 : 5 :
                                    b < 64 ? 6 : 7;
       }

       public static int fL2(int i)
       {
           return
           i < 1 << 15 ? i < 1 << 07 ? i < 1 << 03 ? i < 1 << 01 ? i < 1 << 00 ? -1 : 00 :
                                                                   i < 1 << 02 ? 01 : 02 :
                                                     i < 1 << 05 ? i < 1 << 04 ? 03 : 04 :
                                                                   i < 1 << 06 ? 05 : 06 :
                                       i < 1 << 11 ? i < 1 << 09 ? i < 1 << 08 ? 07 : 08 :
                                                                   i < 1 << 10 ? 09 : 10 :
                                                     i < 1 << 13 ? i < 1 << 12 ? 11 : 12 :
                                                                   i < 1 << 14 ? 13 : 14 :
                         i < 1 << 23 ? i < 1 << 19 ? i < 1 << 17 ? i < 1 << 16 ? 15 : 16 :
                                                                   i < 1 << 18 ? 17 : 18 :
                                                     i < 1 << 21 ? i < 1 << 20 ? 19 : 20 :
                                                                   i < 1 << 22 ? 21 : 22 :
                                       i < 1 << 27 ? i < 1 << 25 ? i < 1 << 24 ? 23 : 24 :
                                                                   i < 1 << 26 ? 25 : 26 :
                                                     i < 1 << 29 ? i < 1 << 28 ? 27 : 28 :
                                                                   i < 1 << 30 ? 29 : 30;
       }

       private static int seed;
       public static Xint RND(int n)
       {
           if (n < 2) return n;
           if (seed == int.MaxValue) seed = 0; else seed++;
           Random rand = new Random(seed);
           byte[] bytes = new byte[(n + 15) >> 3];
           rand.NextBytes(bytes);
           int i = bytes.Length - 1;
           bytes[i] = 0;
           n = (i << 3) - n;
           i--;
           bytes[i] >>= n;
           bytes[i] |= (byte)(128 >> n);
           return new Xint(bytes);
       }
   //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [C# wrapper](http://www.emilstefanov.net/Projects/GnuMpDotNet/) for GNU MP Bignum Library, which is probably as fast as you can get. For pure C# implementation you could try [IntX](http://intx.codeplex.com/).

Fastest multiplication algorithm is actually [Fürer's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCrer%27s_algorithm), but I haven't found any implementations for it.